# uri mapping - '/index.php/dashboard' in nginx

Tags: nginx

In Apache, I can access php scripts through an uri like `/index.php/dashboard`,
how can I set nginx to act the same?

Also I can access `/index` with Apache and it automatically maps to `/index.php`.
Is this also possible in nginx?

I think something like this is the solution:

```
map $uri $myvalue {
    /index.php/(.*)    /index.php?$;
}
```

Or is there a solution w/o rewrite?

My actual config is this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you pass the URI as a query string or what, but if that's the case here's what you could try

```
location ~ /index.php(.*) {
    try_files /index.php?$1 =404;
}
```

Comment: I'm using fpm. The first fastcgi param looks correct, but the location one ends with `$`, should I update the location to `location ~ \.php)(/.+)$` ?